# Best practic to mark slow block of code or method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'd like to mark blocks of code and methods as being slow so that people understand that they work slowly (long).

Is there a preferred way (or tools) to mark blocks of code and methods as being slow in Ruby? May be use special prefix/postfix in method name?

Comment: You could just use [`Kernel#warn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-warn) I guess

Comment: What's wrong with adding a comment before the method? Also, a good practice is to add more details about a change you do in the codebase in the Git history. That way, it will stay with the project for a long time, and people can go back in history and see why a method was implemented in such a (slow) way.
For example, take this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29685) from Rails' repo - the person that worked on the fix explained the problem clearly, showed benchmarks and the difference before/after the fix.

Comment: Slower than what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You should note it in the method's documentation. For example, the documentation for Ruby's [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Time.html) class says: _"When Bignum or Rational is used [...] Time works slower as when integer is used."_

Answer (score 0):

Profiler such as https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof is the standard way.